# Graph API: Not able to fetch attachment saved with contacts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-contacts

I have a contact (**IPM.Contact**) containing a attachment and personal note. I am using Graph Explorer to fetch the contact data. I am able to fetch the contact details with personal note but unable to find the attachment data. I am trying with the URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactFolders/{contactFolderId}/contacts/{contactId}
```

Using **MFCMAPI** I found out that attachment is present under the tag **PR_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS** with hex value **0x0E13**, so I tried expanding it using **singleValueExtendedProperties** and **multiValueExtendedProperties** but both times got

**Error Code:** ErrorUnsupportedMapiPropertyType

**Error Message:** The MAPI property type is not supported.

URL used

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactFolders/{contactFolderId}/contacts/{contactId}?$expand=microsoft.graph.contact/singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Object 0x0E13')

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactFolders/{contactFolderId}/contacts/{contactId}?$expand=microsoft.graph.contact/multiValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Object 0x0E13')
```

Does anyone know how to fetch the contact attachment data?

Comment: Your URLs are correct. Only problem is that PT_OBJECT is not supported by Graph API

Comment: so is there any other way to get the attachment data saved with the contact inside personal note